# .sql file on R studio without any DB software?

Tags: r, dataset, mining

I have a data and this data is 17 GB in .gz format, I downloaded it on the workstation with the account opened to me on my university data lab. This file is unzipped on got  170gb .sql file. How do I use this file in R Studio? Since I connect to the Workstation with IP, I cannot transfer any files from the desktop.